# Can linux signal my Qt program when a particular USB device is connected?

Tags: qt4, usb, signals

I want linux to inform my Qt program by a signal when a particular USB device is connected. Storage devices like flash disk or hard drive. How can I do this? What are your suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

I have found that QtDbus can provide the functionality that I need but I have not figure out how exactly. Is there anyone can give information about getting USB device notification with QtDbus?

I have been reading this tutorial:
http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html

This tutorial says:
D-Bus is designed for two specific cases:

- Communication between desktop applications in the same desktop
  session; to allow integration of the desktop session as a whole, and
  address issues of process life-cycle (when do desktop components start
  and stop running).
- Communication between the desktop session and the operating system,
  where the operating system would typically include the kernel and any
  system daemons or processes.

I am planning to use this facility which I am asking for help in a non-graphical Linux system. More precisely on Beagleboard-XM with Angstrom Linux console image with QWS.

In this circumstances does QtDbus is a correct choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried Qt's DBUS implementation, but the general details of how to get a USB notification are in [this tutorial](http://madison-project.wdfiles.com/local--files/tutorials/Hal_Tutorial.pdf)

The QtDBus function names probably map onto these fairly easily

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look with qdbusviewer from qt4-dev-tools what kind of dbus interface your system has regarding device notification (be it HAL or udev). Than it is relatively simple to generate a c++ implementation with [qdbusxml2cpp](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdbusxml2cpp.html). You will just have to connect to whatever dbus signal your system is suppling for device notification purposes. Here is a quick start guide for qt and dbus [QtDbus Tutorual](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/QtDbus_quick_tutorial).